# Is there any way to avoid code replication across different constructors of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to avoid code replication across different constructors of a class?

```
class sample
{
    int a, b;
    char *c;
public:
    sample(int q) :
      a(0),
      b(0), 
      c(new char [10 * q])
    {
    }

    sample() :
      a(0),
      b(0),
      c(new char [10])
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `q,a,b`? As a user of this class I would find it confusing that `a==b==size of the string*10` while for the other constructor this is not the case. If you would fix that, you could simply provide a default value for `q`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called a delegating constructor. In your case it would look like this:

```
sample(int q) : sample(q, 10 * q)
{
}

sample() : sample(0, 10)
{
}

sample(int q, int d) : a(q),
   b(q), 
   c(new char [d])
{
}
```

Comment: The question is not tagged c++11, so you should precise that this is only available since then.

Comment: Well, you just did it, for me.

Comment: @Holt Being that it is midway through 2016 I would say it is up to the OP to state if they are *not* using C++11 or later.

Comment: @Holt afaik if it is tagged C++ it refers to the latest standard. Imho we woulld rather need a "pre-C++11" tag

Comment: constructor calling constructor ? @Sam Varshavchik

Comment: @CoryKramer This is your opinion, I am not sure this is quite clear that it works this way on SO (just have a look at SO docs... Most topics have block specific to C++11 but none with block specific to C++03 and prior), and in any case, I don't see why adding a little sentence in an answer would harm, it may only makes it less ambiguous.

Comment: @Holt There are indeed `C++98`, `C++03`, `C++11`, `C++14`, and `C++17` tags, all of which I have seen frequently. It is assumed that if you have a question pertaining to a specific one of these standards that you tag it specifically. If just the `C++` tag is added why would we have any reason to believe someone is using some arbitrarily old compiler?

Comment: @Cory - the tag C++ would mean we shouldn't make assumptions about age of the compiler.   Generally, I will treat the C++ tag (if unaccompanied by other tags such as C++11) as needing a solution will work regardless of age of the C++ compiler/library.   There are too many people who are required to maintain ageing code, with constraints (e.g. policy) preventing update to newer compilers.   Essentially your suggestion means they have no way of asking questions.

Comment: @AnooppS - that's, pretty much, all that it boils down to. Google food: "delegating constructors".

Comment: Also might want to add a hint about making the delegating constructor `private`.

Comment: @Peter sure they can : just tag the question [c++03].

Comment: @Quentin - My point is that it is inappropriate to deem "C++" means only the latest C++ standard.   Tagging C++03 (or even C++98) would not help someone to understand C++ code written before the standard was first ratified in 98.   And, yes, there is still such code around in production environments.

Comment: @Peter I personally think that [c++] designating the latest standard is a good thing. If it were (to the extreme) to design "what **all** compilers claiming compliance with *any* C++ standard can compile", SO would be a database of insane kludges from the last century, instead of a valuable resource for current C++ development. Using [c++] for actual, up-to-date C++ and additional tags to restrict it to older standards makes sense. [cont.]

Comment: @Peter On the other hand, your concern about pre-standard C++ dialects is undoubtedly founded, and should IMO be solved with specific tags, probably pointing to the compiler itself rather than the standard (for lack thereof).

Comment: Your argument is equivalent to saying that only the latest model Ford motor vehicle (or any other product for that matter) may be referred to as a Ford.  That's just absurd.   C++ does not need to be a synonym for C++17 (or the latest when any future version comes out).

Comment: @Peter ([relevant Meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309594/3233393), do post an opposite answer if you so wish) --- I'm not convinced of the absurdity, even with your example. Supposing that Ford releases one new car every three years or so, that is meant to replace the previous model, "What kind of spark plugs can I put in my Ford" clearly refers to the current model. You'd have to specify "Ford model 4" to refer to the one that was produced fifty years ago. It may be a bit utopic, but I don't think assuming that everyone has to drag along ancient compilers forever is the way.

Comment: The answer in that meta discussion supports my view more than yours.  i.e. that if a question is tagged C++ (and not tagged for specific versions) the answers should be written with recognition of what the latest standard is, but remain cognisant of ALL possible standards.   And I wouldn't ask "what spark plugs should I punt in my ford?" anyway - I'd ask for spark plugs with the specification (size, gap, etc) that are needed in the engine I have.

Comment: @Peter I didn't mean to link that as an argument, but I've come across it earlier and it'd be a good place to solidify these thoughts. Do note that the answer states that "Without [standard-specific] tags, answerers should already take into account the fact that the current C++ standard is C++14, but *may* [not *should*] also cover C++11, C++03 and C++98".

Comment: I know what the answer said.  And the message you're supporting here (that the C++ tag should mean ONLY the latest standard) is the opposite.  So you may wish to post an alternative to the answer there.  I don't need to, as the answer there supports my position.

Comment: @Peter (this chat link is **badly** misplaced... sorry for that) My opinion is that the [c++] tag, when (and only when) alone, should refer to the latest stadard, that is "today's C++". Answers that include *additional* backwards-compatible solution are of course welcome for their completeness, but should generally be directed towards modern C++, not mention it as a luxury.

Answer (score 2):

In case you *don't* have C++11, you can use a private `void init(...)` function. Note that you cannot initialize const refs this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use in-class initialization.

```
class sample
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    char *c;
public:
    sample(int q) : c(new char [10 * q]) {}
    sample() : c(new char [10]) {}
}
```